# A Function That Converge To The Min After Many Iterations Using Steepest Decent

Tags: optimization

I am searching for a function to show the "zig-zag" pattern of the steepest decent, I want to show that SGD converges after less iterations.

Which functions should look at?

Comment: Wikipedia has an article on [test functions for optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_functions_for_optimization).

Answer (score 1):

Steepest Descent (gradient descent with line search) exhibits zigzag behavior on the Rosenbrock Banana function.

$(x-1)^2 + 100(y-x^2)^2$ using the starting point (-1.2,1). Lots of zigzags to get to the optimum at (1,1). You can make it zigzag even more by increasing 100 to a larger number.